# VNC Server which attaches to current session

Tags: linux, vnc, desktop

I use Debian 9 + fluxbox so there are no 1click enable remote desktop solutions:

http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/tightvnc

The problem with tightvnc, that (at least by default) it will spawn a completely new X session. I don't want that, rather to connect to my currently opened Xorg+fluxbox desktop on my laptop.

Any ways to do this? Am I forced to use commercial software like RealVNC?

Answer (score 0):

[x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) is able to do this by default and is available in the Debian 9 repo. It can be a bit of work to set up but is designed to connect to the X11 session rather than a server.